# How can I increase brightness on Mac without Mac keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, display

I’m using a MacBook Pro and I broke it a while back. So, the keyboard doesn’t work on the laptop. I hooked up a keyboard to the USB port so I can still use it. I’m using a Dell keyboard.

Last night I wanted to listen to music without the brightness of the screen. So without thinking I turned the brightness off. Now I can't get the screen back so I was wondering if there's a way I can use the Dell keyboard to get the screen brightness back?

Comment: What did you do to turn off the brightness? (or are you implying that the F1 key works on the device but not F2?)

Answer (score 41):

key: "**scroll lock**" to decrease brightness
key: "**pause**" to increase brightness

Comment: Oh wow I didn't expect this to work – but Macbook Air 2012 + Yosemite + KBT Pure Pro (TKL) works like a charm!

Comment: I've been looking for this for ages, thank you!!!!

Comment: This is a bit old, but I just stumbled across this. If you're using a programmable keyboard and don't want to use those sometimes the codes are KC_BRID / KC_BRIU for decreasing/increasing, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use Apple Script - if you can ssh into your mac, you can then, in the ssh session, type the following:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"
key code 113
end tell'
```

Please note, that you actually need to press Enter at the end of each line. Also, be careful with the quote characters - there's a single quote after the `-e` option, and then a closing single quote at the end of line 3 above (following the `end tell`). Each execution of the script will increase the brightness by one notch. If you want it dimmer, change `113` to `107`.

If this is something you see yourself use more often, then it might be worth it to either define an alias or write a small shell script, eg:

```
MacBook:~ alias brightup="osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\"
> key code 113
> end tell'"
```

and:

```
MacBook:~ alias brightdn="osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\"
> key code 107
> end tell'"
```

Again, be careful with the quotes. When you put the above aliases into your `.bashrc`, all you'll need to type is `brightup` or `brightdn`.

**Additional info**

If you can't ssh into your box, you can blindly type the first `osascript` command. I would do it in the following way:

1. press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>
2. type `terminal` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. blindly and slowly (and carefully) type the first `osascript...` command from the example above, exactly as it is there. This should bump the brightness up a bit, enough so that you should see what you're doing. If not, try a couple of times to press <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: `BRIGHTNESS_DOWN 0x91` (decimal 145)
`BRIGHTNESS_UP   0x90` (decimal 144)

Answer (score 3):

You could try [resetting the NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) (*a.k.a.* PRAM). Shut down your Mac, then when you turn it back on, holding down <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (<kbd>windows</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> on a PC keyboard) until the computer restarts again.

The NVRAM typically stores hardware settings like brightness, volume, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The "Scroll Lock" and "Page Break" are acting "F14" and "F15", respectively, for non-Apple keyboards. Make sure you turn-off / disconnected the bluetooth / hardware connection to the Apple Keyboard, then the Mac will recognize the non-Apple USB keyboard's "Scroll Lock" and "Page Break" as brightness shortcuts.

Comment: Any idea how to get that to work *without* disabling bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

Use this free application from the apple store
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/brightness-menu-bar/id451140932?mt=12

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Link only answers are insufficient as links can be changed or removed.  What is the App?  How does it solve the problem?  Please update your answer.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you previously use GUI to control brightness, then pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> should turn on the brightness back.

Comment: My experience is that this doesn't work in general; only with an Apple keyboard. When I plugged in a generic USB keyboard, F2 did not adjust brightness and there *was* no FN key to press in combination with F2.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar issue with my macbook pro upon booting. at the login screen (password entry) it is often set to the previous brightness when I shut it down (from what I gather).

I tried the fn 1 and fn2 but nothing worked.  I believe these commands were farmed out to the fancy new bar atop the keyboard (I forget what its called).  regardless, the option to change the brightness isnt available until the machine has booted up a user.

perhaps an update an fix the issue or someone knows a workaround until then.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an app that can control brightness from the AppStore.
the name of app is: Brightness Slider

Answer (score -2):

there is a very simple solution : just reboot

Comment: A simple reboot won't do it. However, holding down **Command** + **Option** + **R** + **P** upon boot increases the screen brightness to the maximum. This boot is also used to reset NVRAM and brightness is one of them.